# how could I write a loop connecting information from two places?

Tags: loops

I need to create a loop in r that fetches the temperature for a specific location and date. I have the date and location in one table and the weather data in another (using the rnoaa package)

Could anyone help me see what this loop would look like?

I don't even know how to start it!